# Dada una palabra y una letra regrese True si la letra está en mayúsculas y minúsculas

Tags: python, funciones

Como hacer programa que dada una palabra y una letra regrese `True` si la letra esta en mayúsculas y minúsculas dentro de la palabra dada. Lo que debe suceder en la funcion es que sea

```py
def enMinyMay(pal,letra):
    for letra in pal:
        if (letra == letra.upper()) and (letra == letra.lower()) :
            return True 
        else:
            return False
```

Siempre me regresa false

Comment: La letra o es mayúscula o es minúscula, no ambas a la vez. ¿Qué quisiste hacer? Por cierto, dale el formato adecuado a tu código.

Comment: ¿Preguntas si la misma letra aparece dos o más veces, al menos una vez en cada formato mayúscula/minúscula?

Comment: revisa los operadores loigicos, quizas tengas un corto circuito

Answer (score 2):

Primer error:

```
def enMinyMay(pal,letra):
    for letra in pal:
```

En el `for` estás reemplazando el parámetro `letra` por el contenido de `pal`. Luego ya no sabes que letra buscar.

Segundo error: Una cosa no puede ser igual a dos cosas distintas. La letra o viene en mayúsculas o en minúsculas.

```
    if (letra == letra.upper()) and (letra == letra.lower()) :
```

Tercer error: Estás iterando con un `for`, pero sólo comparas la primera letra, pues cualquiera sea el resultado del `if`, retornas de inmediato

```
        return True 
    else:
        return False
```

#### Forma correcta

```
def enMinyMay(pal,letra):
    return letra.lower() in pal and letra.upper() in pal
```

Simplemente tienes que preguntar si la forma minúscula está en la palabra y también la forma mayúsculas.

No necesitas recorrer la palabra comparando letra por letra; Python tiene el operador `in` que te dice si un caracter dado está o no dentro de la cadena.

```
tests = [
    "a",
    "A",
    "aA",
    "vaca"
]

for test in tests:
    print(f"Buscar 'a' en {test}: ", enMinyMay(test, 'a'))
```

produce:

```
Buscar 'a' en a:  False
Buscar 'a' en A:  False
Buscar 'a' en aA:  True
Buscar 'a' en vaca:  False

Process finished with exit code 0
```